# HTML: treat special characters as code

Tags: html, special-characters

At our database project, we are using the program dbVisualizer to produce html-output of the result of an SQL query. Unfortunately, this program transforms all the HTML commands entered in the SQL into their HTML special character equivalent.

For example, if I type

---

```
<b>My entry (this time in fat!)</b>
```

---

in the SQL code, I want to see the same as well in the html source.

However, the export option rather transforms it into

---

```
&lt;b &gt; My entry (this time in fat!)&lt;/b &gt;
```

---

With this, the text is displayed in the browser as `<b>My entry (this time in fat!)</b>`, i.e. as I entered it. But this is not what I was looking for, I'd rather want to obtain the *action* of the tags.

**So, is there a way to tell HTML to treat the special characters as their code-equivalent, without using JavaScript and PHP** (which is not an option in this program)**?** That is, when the browser encounters `&lt;b &gt;`, is there a way it is treated as `<b>` (e.g. by using some special charset or another option)?

Comment: You will have to *not escape* the text. Your "export option" needs to support that somehow.

Comment: Quentin gave you the right answer. Don't you have any escape character that would translate to < while exporting?

Comment: Yes, looking/asking for that will be the next step.

Comment: (Quentin answered the question you asked.) The issue is with "the program dbVisualizer" producing "**html-output  of the result of a SQL query.**". It's that program that's doing the "encoding" (escaping, if you will) of the HTML tags, so that what's in the query will be displayed in the browser. The "html-output" feature/function of that program is specifically designed to *prevent* the contents of a resultset from being interpreted as HTML tags. (You'd need an option/function/feature in that program to *disable* the HTML encoding of the result. There's no workaround available in the HTML.)

Comment: @specer7593: thanks, this is what I meant with "next step": look whether the program can manage it somehow, and if not possibly ask for extension. But before that I wanted to ensure that it isn't possible with native html.

Comment: In dbVisualizer, there seems to be no such option at the moment, see [here](http://www.dbvis.com/forum/thread.jspa?threadID=4963).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't. HTML has no such feature.